# Good Apple Hunting

Tags: cipher, story, situation, computer-science

The boys brought him in for questioning, but I didn't think he had anything to do with this. Not really. I just had to know if he knew anything pertinent about that strange passage in the old man's will.

I proceeded to tell him how his old computer science teacher, Professor Lambeau, had been found.

"The victim was strapped securely to a chair in his office. There was a robotic arm on a table across from him that had been retrofitted so that it could shoot a laser out of its index finger. The arm was attached to a computer and the program was coded to rotate the arm slowly up from its initial downward-facing position at a rate of one degree per hour, a la 1960's Batman villains. Eventually, it reached the victim's crotchular region and continued up until the victim was cut cleanly in two.

"We suspect foul play.

"This is his will, and there's a strange section in it which is directed at you, Will. Does this mean anything to you?"

Will, apparently bored, skimmed over the document, probably understanding more of it than any of us did, but when he got to the section addressed to him, he grabbed a notebook and scribbled furiously for about 30 seconds before declaring, "We have to go see about a girl, Detective. She's the killer and I know her name."

He was right, of course, and time to time I reread that passage late at night.

> To my former student Will: In the event of my untimely demise, I want you to know that I still remember that conversation we once had:
>
> You ate my apple.
> *For what possible reason would I eat your apple?*
> Do you take me for a fool? One would hope not!
> *I didn't, OK, but let's say I ate your apple. Would you like for me to eat one more? Three more???*
> Maybe you ate four of them already! Maybe you took my watermelon, too?
> *Yeah, OK, I ate your watermelon, for your information, but I didn't eat even one of those apples, you old fart!*

Now everyone knows that Will is *wicked smaat* and well known for his love of apples, but I'll never know what that message had to do with the killer's name!

**Do you know the killer's name?**

Hints:

> As mentioned in the comment below, **The capital letter "I" is not a "one" because it is pronounced /aɪ/, not /wʌn/.**
>  The "Computer-Science" tag might make you wonder if one of the numerical "clues" is inappropriate; a red herring.
>  I would hate for the bounty to be unrewarded.
>  There are 6 (six) parts to this conversational exchange. During each part, Will finds time to secretly take a nibble(sp?) from an apple. The professor notices and uses this to his advantage.
>  BTW, Nothing Boolean, only the integers.

Another Hint:

> Paste's comment, "Assigning each line to a nibble, I came up with 1000 0100 0101 1111 1110 1101." brings us ***very*** close.

Comment: Is knowledge of Good Will Hunting necessary to solve this?

Comment: Does Alan Turing's untimely demise relate to this?

Comment: Not at all. The Good Will Hunting stuff is just for fun. The only pertinent information is in the passage directed at Will.

Comment: **I added TWO hints.**  
 One is from a comment on the only answer attempted at this point.  
The other three may help as well.

Comment: Is Apple (iPhone & iMac) related to this in any way?

Comment: wicked smaat, is that misspelled or something? what does it mean?

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat You need to read it like you are from South Boston (aka Southy).  You can paaaak your caaaaaaa in the yaaaaaad.  (You can park your car in the yard).

Comment: And I still have no firm idea how to solve this puzzle, but I love that scene.

Comment: Wait, in the hint, did you mean not to pay attention to that particular number, or that thinking it's irrelevant is a mistake?

Comment: @paste One of the numbers *does not belong with the others.* There! I said it!

Comment: I wonder if [this apple ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f34e/index.htm) and [this watermelon ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f349/index.htm) play any part?

Comment: I feel there is binary subtraction involved. The fact that Will loves Apples, and he takes a nibble of an apple secretly (given the nibbles), there is a potential in binary subtraction there.

Comment: Unless this is supposed to be a name: �_� then I would say it's the Riddler (the whole Batman villain from 1960's)

Comment: I got the nibbles as soon as you posted the nibble hint, but I've been stuck there since

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnZ0Y4rvz6E

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why, her name was

> Jenny, of course.

Explanation:

First, what everyone has deduced so far:

> So far, we've figured out that each line of the conversation has homophones of powers of 2 in it:
>  You ate my apple. = 8
>  For what possible reason would I eat your apple? = 4
>  Do you take me for a fool? One would hope not! = 4 and 1
>  I didn't, OK, but let's say I ate your apple. Would you like for me to eat one more? Three more??? = 8, 4, 2, 1
>  Maybe you ate four of them already! Maybe you took my watermelon, too? = 8, 4, 2
>  Yeah, OK, I ate your watermelon, for your information, but I didn't eat even one of those apples, you old fart! = 8, 4, 1
>  Taking each of these lines' numbers and making them into nibbles (4-bit sequences) with 1's for each digit present, we get
>  `8xxx x4xx x4x1 8421 842x 84x1`
>  `1000 0100 0101 1111 1110 1101`.

Then,

> Crunch the nibbles together to get one binary number: `100001000101111111101101`. What is that in decimal? It's `8675309`, and as any true 80's music aficionado would know, that number belongs to Jenny. [Just ask Tommy Tutone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WTdTwcmxyo).

How do you like them apples?

Comment: That's good work. To think of all the time I wasted trying to break that number down in different ways. A well deserved +1!

Comment: You got a number... of course :)

Comment: Just had to read the writing on the wall.

Comment: [You got it (you got it) you got it You got the number on the wall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WTdTwcmxyo&feature=youtu.be&t=120)

Comment: Brilliant...simply brilliant!

Comment: Who can I turn to? -- Paste, apparently! +1 Bravo!

Answer (score 5):

Partial just to try and point out the numbers:

You ate my apple.
(ate = 8)

For what possible reason would I eat your apple?
(For = 4)

Do you take me for a fool? One would hope not!
(For = 4, One = 1)

I didn't, OK, but let's say I ate your apple. Would you like for me to eat one more? Three more???
(ate = 8, for = 4, to = 2, one = 1, three = 3 (nope a red herring))

Maybe you ate four of them already! Maybe you took my watermelon, too?
(ate = 8, four = 4, too = 2)

Yeah, OK, I ate your watermelon, for your information, but I didn't eat even one of those apples, you old fart!
(ate = 8, for = 4, one = 1)

Assigning each line to a nibble yields:
Binary: `1000 0100 0101 1111 1110 1101`
Decimal: `8 4 5 15 14 13`

I'm searching for a 15 character string to use as a key for the substitution.  Something to do with WATERMELON or APPLE or OLD FART.  (I tried WATERMELONAPPLE and APPLEWATERMELON)

Comment: I didn't, OK, but let's say I ate your apple. Would you like for me to eat one more? Three more??? 
 (ate = 8, for = 4, one = 1, three = 3)  
**nothing for "to"?**  
"Yeah, OK, I ate your watermelon, for your information, but I didn't eat even one of those apples, you old fart!
 (ate = 8, one = 1)   **nothing for "for"?**

No "red herrings?" There! I said it!

Comment: I think three is the red herring. The rest are all powers of 2, but I haven't been able to come up with any sensible decoding.

Comment: @MikeM, I have no idea.  I think I have all the numbers now.

Comment: Yep, those are what I have, except I didn't count the "not"s. Maybe I should - at least the one not in the contraction - but that kills my reasoning for three being the red herring.

Comment: OP said no booleans.

Comment: @paste I'm referring to naught, or zero, the integer. OP's statement about Booleans is kind of ambiguous, so it's hard to tell exactly what they meant. How are you interpreting it?

Comment: The powers of two are also in decreasing order within each quip. That might suggest that they encode bits, e.g. 841 is 1101. That would make the code 8, 4, 5, 13, 14, 13. I can't make anything sensible out of it, not even with a shift of three in either direction.

Comment: @MikeM.In the answer above, he refers to them as "not", so i assumed he was treating them as acting as a complement to some representation.

Comment: @paste Oh, I get ya. I was reading it as they were unsure whether we should translate "not" to "naught", but that makes more sense, now that I reread it.

Comment: Yeah you guys are on the same line as me, but I still make no sense of it.  I'm not sure the hints are helping or hurting.

Comment: Assigning each line to a [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble), I came up with 1000 0100 0101 1111 1110 1101. No idea what to do with those though. Assigning them letters just yields gibberish.

Comment: @paste Assigning "letters"?

Comment: Using the binary/numbers, I got 8 - 4 - 41 - 8421 - 842 - 841. Based on the letters I got, it seems `Mary` is the closest (from a list of letters of R-Y-M-A-F), and that's the wildest guess ever. What do you think @Chowzen ?

Comment: @Adib is this an answer to the question in comment form?

Comment: @Adib how does 8.4.41.8421.842.841 become RYMAF?

Comment: 8,4,5,15,14,13 -> h, d, e, o, n, m

Comment: @Chowzen I assigned each nibble a letter based on the A=1, B=2... schema. I came up with what ev3commander got, just above this comment.

Comment: @paste  No need for any binary encoding to get those results. The sums are the same adding in base 10. If binary is indeed important here, I would think it must be so in some other manner.

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah, I realized that. I tried assembling them into full bytes, transposing them, switching high and low nibbles, grouping them based on who said the line they came from... no dice.

Comment: Yep, it's getting frustrating. :-) I've hit all these same things the last couple days, but no real progress. I thought maybe the powers of 2 themselves - 3 2 2 0 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 3 2 0 - might be the encoding, but nothing there yet, either. And one of OP's comments makes me think that's not it. I'm really thinking "apple" has to be some sort of key, but that might be entirely off.

Comment: If the 3 is meant to be there then 8,4,5,18,14,13->h,d,e,r,n,m

Comment: In groups of 5,  paste's nibbles become 10000|10001|01111|11110|1101, or 16 17 15 30 13, or p q o (something) m.

Comment: @ev3commander But a nibble is only 4 bits, so 18 can't be in a nibble.  So you would have to deal with the overflow.

Comment: On the other hand, since a nibble is half a byte, we can try 10000100|01011111|11101101. (someone convert pls?)

Comment: 132, 95, 237. Does that have to do with anything?

Comment: I think I'm going to open a restaurant called Paste's Nibbles.

Comment: @paste Not interested in eating paste, did that enough a long time ago.

Comment: @ev3commander The bits returned : �_� (the look of confusion)

Comment: Note that in hex, they are 8 4 5 F E D. Not that that yields anything of meaning.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Out of curiosity, how were you going to use the 15 character string?

Comment: @paste Map each of the nibbles to a character in the string

Comment: @LeppyR64 Ah, right.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Yang

Reason:

> Took all the numbers in the quote (ate -> 8, for -> 4, etc.) and put them in a sequence which got me 8441413842841. I converted this to ASCII which got me "Niào" which I searched and don't think is a girl's name. Then I decided to remove the lone "2" in the sequence and converted that instead which got me "Yang"

Comment: Can you explain how you converted it to ascii?

Comment: Sorry,no. I like the idea of "conversion," and am curious (like LeppyR64) as to how you got "Yang" or even "Niào" from *that* sequence of numbers by way of ascii.

**BONUS: the capital letter "I" is not a "one" because it is pronounced /aɪ/, not /wʌn/**

Comment: i just used an online converter XD i think it converted it to binary first if that makes more sense.

Comment: I think you're certainly on to something with the numbers.  I was working on the same path but hadn't had time to suss it out.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure it's something to do with that. There's no cryptography tag so I was hoping it'd be something simple like converting to ASCII.

Comment: You are missing a number in your sequence.

Comment: ...and that's only if you only consider the conversation and not the introduction to it.

Comment: @paste The introduction is merely an introduction. The conversation.is the key.

Comment: @ econoMichael:  I suppose that the cryptography tag would apply here as well.  Will add it now.

Comment: @paste Assuming we're just looking at the conversation, more than one number is missing in the above sequence

Comment: @question_asker Ah, you're right. So far I'm counting 15 total...

Comment: @Chowzen damn cryptography. i never stood a chance

Comment: @econoMichael Crypto's not an impenetrable area of study. This might be a good opportunity (or at least impetus) to look into it more!

Answer (score 3):

Using the binary/numbers, I got 8 - 4 - 5 (For, One) - 15 - 14 - 13.

Based on the letters I got, it seems `Mary` is the closest (from a list of letters of R-Y-M-A-F-Y-M-W). How I derived the letters was counting from the start using the values provided to and find the letters based on the word.

For example, the 8th word is "reason", so I pulled an "R". And then 4 steps ahead I got "Your", so I pulled "Y", etc.

Another approach is using the numbers to find the letters, which yields:

8th letter, 4th letter, 5th letter, etc....And I get:

8 -> H
4 -> D
5 -> E
15 -> O
14 -> N
13 -> M

Which really made no sense, so I ignored this approach.

Comment: Never knew it would be this much fun "reverse engineering" the proposed answer(s) to my own riddle. +1 to Adib for the effort!