# There's no place like Home Theater!

Tags: wordplay, story, knowledge

Dorothy, now 93 years old, was watching some of her favorite movies in her home theater when, as one would expect in tornadic climes such as Kansas, her house blew away to somewhere over the rainbow.
"Not again!" Dorothy cried to her dog, Toto #6.
Looking around at the wreckage of her home, she noticed something peculiar. All of her DVD's had fused together magically here in the land of OZ. The titles of her movies were unreadable, but the fused descriptions of these films were still intact:

1. A lawyer defends a black man who ruthlessly gunned down a songbird.
2. In post-apocolyptic Australia, surviving humans are attacked by driverless trucks.
3. A superhero-turned-pimp operates his business out of a morgue.
4. A group of diamond thieves ends up taking hostages in a bank.
5. A debt collector for the mob befriends a quirky diner waitress.
6. A widow and her three daughters can see dead people.
7. A bunch of vampire boys play baseball all summer inspite of the devil-dog lurking next door.
8. A jilted man travels all the way under the sea to stalk a beautiful fish.
9. An aspiring wizard moves to New York with a high-maintenance blonde.
10. A troubled veteran gets a job chauffering an elderly woman
11. A tough-as-nails dancing cop with a powerful handgun gets an infant out of a corner.
12. In the near future, a mentally challenged cop uses farm equipment to kill androids.

BONUS question: Three movies fused together:
A math genius mobster, accused of murder, is acquitted with the help of his young, military lawyer.

> Can you determine the new, fused movie title for each, based on the new movie descriptions?

***BONUS*** **HINT**

> The bonus has nothing angry or rainy about it.

**EDIT**
Reworded the question. The answers should be a single title composed of parts of the original two (or more, BONUS) movie titles.
TV Show Example: *Happy Days* fused with *Days of our Lives* would create:
*Happy Days of our Lives*.
Sorry for the inaccurate question phrasing!  :)

Comment: I would pay to see those to be honnest.

Comment: Excellent intro :) RIP Totos 1-5.

Comment: "All of her DVD's had fused together " you mean pairs had fused together? It sounds like a single block, a d took a while to figure out otherwise.

Comment: @JDługosz separate movies magically became one movie, with a new, appropriate title and plot.

Comment: **in pairs**, not all, of them, together, as one big mass.

Comment: You're not fooling anyone, we all know you left out your favorite combo: Divine Secrets of the Ya-Ya Sisterhood of the Traveling Pants

Comment: @whrrgarbl You'd maybe like this [question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32762/good-apple-hunting) then.

Comment: Come on, you're in OZ, unfuse 'em!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A lawyer defends a black man who ruthlessly gunned down a songbird.

> A Time to Kill a Mockingbird (A Time To Kill / To Kill A Mockingbird)

In post-apocolyptic Australia, surviving humans are attacked by driverless trucks.

> Mad Maximum Overdrive (Mad Max / Maximum Overdrive)

A superhero-turned-pimp operates his business out of a morgue.

> The Dark Knight Shift (The Dark Knight / Night Shift)

A group of diamond thieves end up taking hostages in a bank.

> Reservoir Dog Day Afternoon (Reservoir Dogs / Dog Day Afternoon)

A debt collector for the mob befriends a quirky diner waitress.

> As Good As It Gets Shorty (As Good As It Gets / Get Shorty)

A widow and her three daughters can see dead people.

> The Sixth Sense and Sensibility (The Sixth Sense / Sense and Sensibility)

A bunch of vampire boys play baseball all summer inspite of the devil-dog lurking next door.

> Salem's Sandlot (Salem's Lot / The Sandlot)

A jilted man travels all the way under the sea to stalk a beautiful fish.

> Finding Neverland / Finding [Nemo/Dory] *only half correct

An aspiring wizard moves to New York with a high-maintenance blonde.

> When Harry Potter met Sally (When Harry met Sally / Harry Potter and the …)

A troubled veteran gets a job chauffering an elderly woman

> Taxi Driving Miss Daisy (Taxi Driver / Driving Miss Daisy)

A tough-as-nails dancing cop with a powerful handgun gets an infant out of a corner.

> Dirty Harry Dancing (Dirty Harry / Dirty Dancing)

In the near future, a mentally challenged cop uses farm equipment to kill androids.

> Sling Blade Runner (Sling Blade / Blade Runner

A math genius mobster, accused of murder, is acquitted with the help of his young, military lawyer.

> A Few Goodfellas Will Hunting Men (A Few Good Men / GoodFellas / Good Will Hunting) (*almost right; via @Dan Russell)

Comment: Good start, #5 and #8 are only partially correct. Also, see **EDIT** in question for answer formatting.

Comment: ".A debt collector for the mob" doesn't sound like "Goodfellas" to me... "GoodFellas" may show up in another answer, though.

Comment: "A jilted man travels...to stalk a beautiful..." Hmmmmm...

Comment: forgetting?  Dealing with issues of my own...You get the prize.

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer:

A lawyer defends a black man who ruthlessly gunned down a songbird.

> A Time to Kill / To Kill a Mockingbird

An aspiring wizard moves to New York with a high-maintenance blonde.

> Harry Potter / When Harry met Sally

A tough-as-nails dancing cop with a powerful handgun gets an infant out of a corner.

> Dirty Harry / Dirty Dancing

A math genius mobsster, accused of murder, is acquitted with the help of his young, military lawyer.

> Good Will Hunting OR Rain Man / ?? / A Few Good Men

Answer (score 3):

Only got one so far

A tough-as-nails dancing cop with a powerful handgun gets an infant out of a corner.

> Dirty Harry/Dirty Dancing  **EDIT by Chowzen** Intended answer: "Dirty Harry Dancing" Both film names fused into one.

Answer (score 3):

### Partial answer:

2. In post-apocolyptic Australia, surviving humans are attacked by driverless trucks.

> Mad **Max**imum Overdrive (Mad Max + Maximum Overdrive)

Answer (score 3):

Since the bonus has not yet been solved, here's my attempt. Thanks to Bunjiquobianco for supplying 1 and 3.

> Rain Man/Twelve Angry Men/A few good men.

Comment: A Few Good Angry Rain Men?

Comment: A Few Good Will Hunting Twelve Angry Men?

Answer (score 3):

Bonus?

> A Few Goodfellas Will Hunting Men

Comment: Not *exactly* what I had in mind. Close enough to stir the pot. Deserves my (and others') plus 1