# Muddled movie titles

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

A friend of mine has a really (selectively) bad memory, and often gets things muddled. He's trying to recall the titles of these movies / series, but all he can give me is a very brief synopsis of each. However, he remembers exactly how many words are in each title. Can you help us out?

> 1. A tough police inspector tracks down a psychopath with magic (3)
> 2. A nurse and a Frenchman sing while battling leviathans (3)
> 3. A large and hairy suburban father cools his temper to win over a teenage girl (5)
> 4. A man convinces a secret organization that an extraterrestrial is innocent (5)
> 5. A misfit librarian tries to protect his son from an inept anti-Semitic circus troupe (5)
> 6. A ruthless oilman and a preacher fight over a precious pink gemstone (5)
> 7. A nun hides in a mall from a convicted killer who is now a flesh-eating zombie (6)
> 8. An uncultured flower seller shares pasta with a streetwise mutt (6)
> 9. A young man time travels to train with an eccentric master frog (7)
> 10. A suave man gets trapped in a massive ice storm twice (7)

---

**Editor's note (spoilers ahead):**

> Although I searched before posting I didn't realize that [Chowzen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22519/chowzen) had a [very similar idea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/36096/15629). I gave myself 3 rules though which meant my format was a little stricter:
>
>  1. Titles would only be connected end-to-end
>  2. The joining word's form must be exactly the same (e.g. singular vs. plural, verb tense)
>  3. However, articles can be dropped.
>
>  There has already been one spin-off posted which doesn't follow all of those rules, which is totally fine! Just wanted to explain how I came up with them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A tough police inspector tracks down a psychopath with magic (3)

> Dirty Harry Potter (Dirty Harry + Harry Potter)

A nurse and a Frenchman sing while battling leviathans (3)

> South Pacific Rim (South Pacific + Pacific Rim)

A large and hairy suburban father cools his temper to win over a teenage girl (5)

> American Beauty and the Beast

A man convinces a secret organization that an extraterrestrial is innocent (5)

> Twelve Angry Men in Black (Twelve angry men + men in black)

A misfit librarian tries to protect his son from an inept anti-Semitic circus troupe (5)

> A Bug's Life is Beautiful? (A bug's life + life is beautiful)

A ruthless oilman and a preacher fight over a precious pink gemstone (5)

> There Will Be Blood Diamond (There Will Be Blood + Blood Diamond)

A nun hides in a mall from a convicted killer who is now a flesh-eating zombie (6)

> Dawn of the Dead Man Walking (Dawn of the dead + dead man walking)

An uncultured flower seller shares pasta with a streetwise mutt (6)

> My Fair Lady and the Tramp (My Fair Lady + Lady and the Tramp)

A young man time travels to train with an eccentric master frog (7)

> The Empire Strikes Back to the Future (The Empire Strikes Back + Back to the Future)

A suave man gets trapped in a massive ice storm twice (7)

> Die Another Day After Tomorrow Never Dies (Die Another Day, The Day After Tomorrow, Tomorrow Never Dies). [Thanks @SGR]

Comment: I think I've got nearly all of them. The last one doesn't fit the pattern, but it's too funny, so I've included it anyway.

Comment: Haha, all correct except the last one. I definitely would not have put Tom Cruise as the "suave man" :D

Comment: Well, there's a Bond one, but that would only make 6 words...

Comment: Ah... to clarify, articles can be dropped. I meant to set that as a precedent in an earlier clue but I guess the last one is the only one where that happens

Comment: I've had another go at it. A bit of a stretch to make it seven words.

Comment: I like your interpretation of "twice" but that is not quite correct. Right idea with 3 movies though

Comment: Master frog? In what way is that character a frog?

Comment: @KaiQing Probably refers to Yoda.

Comment: @noedne: I think Kai Qing understood who it referred to - hence their question: "in what way is that character a frog?" Being green isn't really enough on its own...

Comment: Well he’s small, green, nimble, sounds like a frog :) Just trying to keep it light hearted without making the answer too obvious

Comment: Now I'm just imagining Star Wars with Kermit instead of Yoda. Actually, the entire movie with muppets would be amazing. Get on it Disney!

Comment: @Kruga I remember reading once that George Lucas joked that Yoda is Kermit's son.

Comment: I would like to see some of them actuall :D

Answer (score 6):

Is 10

> Die Another Day After Tomorrow Never Dies (Die Another Day, The Day After Tomorrow, Tomorrow Never Dies).

Comment: I think so. Mind if I use it?

Comment: @jsm Go for it.

Comment: That is correct :)