# Muddled video games titles

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, video-games

*First of all, this is totally a rip-off of [@ferret idea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66190/muddled-movie-titles), but with video games instead of movies.*

So, basically the same story: I have a friend that use to mix things up and is unable to clearly describe what he is talking about. However, he always knows exactly the number of words of each title. It's just that... the titles are mixed up also. Can you help me finding what are those video games he's mentioning?

> 1. Schoolgirls and a scientist breaking physics (4)
> 2. Prisoners fend off Lovecraftian horrors by protecting a crystal (5)
> 3. People fighting zombies fighting a killer fighting people (5)
> 4. Millions of plumbers killing thousands of creatures on two continents (5)
> 5. Heroes playing football to destroy the enemy cars (4)
> 6. Engineer fighting pixelated aliens in a spaceship (3)
> 7. Dragon slayer going on an infinite and disappointing journey (3)
> 8. People fighting the Empire with an inappropriate tool (6)
> 9. Family punching trees to survive the war (4)
> 10. People with swords dying a lot in a haunted mansion (6)

Comment: Sweet :D And although I came up with mine separately I want to give Chowzen a shoutout for his [similar puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/36096/15629) from almost 2 years ago!

Comment: @ferret This exact same mechanic was in a Cisra _(or maybe Sums?)_ puzzle 5-10 years ago -- in fact I even remember a few of the answers from your puzzle being answers there.  I'm certain it's just coincidence; my point is just that this puzzle mechanic is not a recent invention.

Comment: Only 8 & 10 are still unsolved at this moment! Do not hesitate to gather all answers with due respect to their finders, the green checkmark will go to the most complete answer as usual ;)

Comment: @BlueRaja oh sure, not surprising at all!

Comment: The format is quite old, and was I think popularized by its recurring presence as the [Before and After](https://www.wheeloffortune.com/in-case-you-missed-it/before-after) category on Wheel of Fortune and subsequently Jeopardy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a complete answer, I only found one/two so most credit is to the others contributors.

```
1. Schoolgirls and a scientist breaking physics (4)
```

> Half-Life is Strange (@Saeïdryl)

```
 2. Prisoners fend off Lovecraftian horrors by protecting a crystal (5)
```

> Darkest Dungeon of the Endless (@gustavo gabriel)

```
 3. People fighting zombies fighting a killer fighting people (5)
```

> Left 4 Dead by Daylight (@Kant1)

```
 4. Millions of plumbers killing thousands of creatures on two continents (5)
```

> Super Mario World of Warcraft (@PL457)

```
 5. Heroes playing football to destroy the enemy cars (4)
```

> Rocket League of Legends

```
 6. Engineer fighting pixelated aliens in a spaceship (3)
```

> Dead Space Invaders (@Kant1)

```
 7. Dragon slayer going on an infinite and disappointing journey (3)
```

> No Man's Skyrim (@Kant1)

```
  8. People fighting the Empire with an inappropriate tool (6)
```

> Shovel Knights of the Old Republic (@Ian MacDonald)

```
  9. Family punching trees to survive the war (4)
```

> This War of Minecraft (@Saeïdryl)

```
  10. People with swords dying a lot in a haunted mansion (6)
```

> Alone in the Dark Souls Calibur (@Saeïdryl and me for the last game)

Comment: 3. is not good, @Kant1 fixed it ;)

Comment: fixed in this answer too!

Answer (score 16):

My Small contribution :

(not sure) 
3.People fighting zombies fighting a killer fighting people (5)

> EDITED : Left 4 Dead  <s>or Alive</s> by Daylight

6. Engineer fighting pixellated aliens in a spaceship (3)

> Dead Space Invaders

7. Dragon slayer going on an infinite and disappointing journey (3)

> No Man's Skyrim

Comment: All 3 are good now ;)

Answer (score 16):

4) Millions of plumbers killing thousands of creatures on two continents (5)

> Super Mario World of Warcraft

Answer (score 14):

Let's begin slowly

```
1. Schoolgirls and a scientist breaking physics (4)
```

> Half-life is strange

```
9. Family punching trees to survive the war (4)
```

> This War of Minecraft

This one doesn't fit but...

```
10.People with swords dying a lot in a haunted mansion (6)
```

> Alone in the Dark Souls

Comment: for nr 10, there are multiple games in the series, adding a sequel number will get you 6 words. I don't know if it is cheating though :P

Comment: Let's say there is a common point with @ferret's 10th clue ;)

Comment: I thought about that too, but that was cheating for me :(

Comment: @Keelhaul Soul(s) smth ?

Comment: @Saeïdryl quite possibly ;)

Comment: @Keelhaul is 10 related to rot13(7 qnlf gb qvr)? Since you said that  there is a common point with ferret's 10th clue.

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Not at all :p

Answer (score 12):

2. Prisoners fend off lovecraftian horrors by protecting a crystal (5)

> Darkest Dungeon of the Endless

Answer (score 9):

8. People fighting the Empire with an inappropriate tool (6)

> Shovel Knights of the Old Republic
>
>  *Although, technically, the Old Republic was the precursor to the Galactic Empire, and in the KOTOR series, the enemy is the Sith.*

Comment: Well done, one more to go!