# Orange you glad it's not Lemon?

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

> My friend gave me this note in class,
>
> my very own third grade mathematics class!
>
> But alas:
>
> To little, my third grade-ly efforts amassed.
>
> Again and again,
>
> I wish I'd known then,
>
> I needn't try to compute.
>
> What was my little friend's favorite fruit?

```
65 27 66 49 54 32 17 62 44 30 71 59 19 68 48 67 62 38 67 21 24 64 54 57 43 67 37 

84 66 67 68 71 65 66 80 65 54 87 54 61 83 49 88 57 64 78 67 57 62 51 76 50 73 50
```

Hint 1:

> Although the poem will assist your journey,
>  About all but its plaintext, you needn't worry.

Hint 2:

> Heed this advice as if from some advisor:
>  This puzzle involves fewer than one cipher.

Hint 3:

> The teacher said something 'bout a bug on the ceiling...
>  I'm sure that the lesson would have been revealing!

Comment: @North Thanks for the consideration, but the answer to the question is not hinted to at all in the poem. The numbers hold the answer. Would this still be considered a riddle?

Comment: I don't want to give too much away here of course, but the first hint is true at face value. The only thing you should pay attention to in the poem is what it is actually saying: no tricky trickery tricks.

Comment: Alright, then you can reject the riddle tag added. However, I'd advise getting rid of the number-sequence tag, because number sequence is finding the next number in the sequence (hence its name) and it doesn't seem like your asking us to find the next number. Of course, disregard this comment if I am wrong.

Comment: @North I thought the tag just indicated that the puzzle involved lists of numbers. Accordingly, I will now remove the tag.

Comment: Last thing: Does this puzzle require any mathematics to solve? A cipher tag would be more appropriate here, especially with your new hint. Also, please don't add a mathematic tag or number tag just because you have numbers in your puzzle. It throws users off if this is a monoalphabetic or polyalphabetic cipher using numbers. Thank you!

Comment: @North To answer this clearly would give too much information, but the Mathematics tag is definitely correct, and so is the lack of the Cipher tag.

Comment: I **cannot** believe I didn't see this, especially when you consider [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61920/not-bingo-not-snoopy).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

His favourite fruit is a

> Banana

The numbers are

> coordinates in the plane, in the first line are the x-coordinates and on the second line are the y-coordinates. So the point are (65, 84), (27, 66), etc.
>  If we draw all these points, we get the following:
>  [image]

Comment: bravo.  I spent too much time working on numerics

Comment: +1 for *yellow* plot points.